# Why `Flux.generate()` is never requested?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

Consider the following code:

```
  @Test
  void testTooMuchBuffering2() {
    var counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    var lastCollected = new AtomicInteger(-1);
    Flux.<List<Integer>>generate(
            sink -> {
              int val = counter.getAndAdd(1000);
              if (val >= 10_000) {
                sink.complete();
                return;
              }
              // Read 1000 rows from a "database"
              System.out.println("\nGenerating " + (val + 1000));
              sink.next(IntStream.range(val, val + 1000).boxed().toList());
            })
        .doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("Subscribed"))
        .doOnRequest(r -> System.out.println("flatMapIterable: " + r)) // Never executes
        .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
        .doOnRequest(r -> System.out.println("blockLast: " + r))
        .blockLast();
  }
```

The `doOnRequest()` above `flatMapIterable()` never gets executed. The output of this test is:

```
Subscribed
blockLast: 9223372036854775807
Generating 1000
Generating 2000
Generating 3000
Generating 4000
Generating 5000
Generating 6000
Generating 7000
Generating 8000
Generating 9000
Generating 10000
```

Why isn't the lambda in`doOnRequest()` invoked here?
In [other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78118097/why-is-flux-reactor-buffering-so-many-elements), too much is requested and here nothing is ever requested. Why?

Comment: Look at `flatMapIterable`. It looks like it inspects the sources `Spliterator` and then just creates a new collection and streams that. If you change the source from `Flux.<List<Integer>>` to something without a list I think that `FlatMapIterable` will give you troubles. Beyond this, I don't know.

Comment: @K.Nicholas If I add, right above `blockLast()`, `.buffer(100).doOnRequest(...).flatMapIterable(Function.identity())` the new `doOnRequest()` does print, but not the one I am asking about.

Comment: I'll bet if you add, right above `blockLast()`, `.buffer(100).doOnRequest(...).flatMapIterable(Function.identity())` the new `doOnRequest()` does print, but not the one you're asking about.